# Dataflow autoscale does not boost performance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm building a Dataflow pipeline that reads from pubsub and sends requests to a 3rd party API. The pipeline use `THROUGHPUT_BASED` autoscaling.

However when I was doing a load test against it, after it autoscaled to 4 works to catch up with the backlog in pubsub, but it seems the same workload was spread out event between works, but overall throughput did not increase significantly.

[image: Number of unacknowledged messages in pubsub. The peak is when traffic stopped going in]
^ Number of unacknowledged messages in pubsub. The peak is when traffic stopped going in

[image: Bytes sent from each worker.]
^ Bytes sent from each worker. The peak is the initial worker. As more workers were added to the pool, the workload is offloaded, instead of each of them picking up more workload. The CPU utilization looks the same, where the peak utilization is below 30% for the initial worker.

[image: The history of worker spawned]
^ The history of worker spawned.

It feels like either there is a limitation being hit somewhere, but I have a hard time seeing what the limitation is. I was pulling less than 300 messages per second, and each message is about 1kb.

**Update:**
I did another round of comparison between batched job using TextIO and streaming job using PubSubIO, both with "n1-standard-8" machines and fixed number of workers to 15. The batched job went up to 450 elements/s, but the streaming job still peaked at 230 elements/s. It seems the limitation is coming from the source. Although I'm not sure what was the limitation.

**Update 2**
Here is a simple code snippet to reproduce the issue. You will need to manually set number of works to 1 and 5 and compare the number of element processed by the pipeline. You will need a load tester to efficiently publish messages to the topic.

```
package debug;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;

public class DebugPipeline {
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static PipelineResult main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        /*******************************************
         * SETUP - Build options.
         ********************************************/

        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
                .as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
        options.setAutoscalingAlgorithm(
                DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.AutoscalingAlgorithmType.THROUGHPUT_BASED);
        // Autoscaling will scale between n/15 and n workers, so from 1-15 here
        options.setMaxNumWorkers(15);
        // Default of 250GB is absurdly high and we don't need that much on every worker
        options.setDiskSizeGb(32);
        // Manually configure scaling (i.e. 1 vs 5 for comparison)
        options.setNumWorkers(5);

        // Debug Pipeline
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        pipeline
            .apply(PubsubIO.readStrings()
                    .fromSubscription("your subscription"))
            // this is the transform that I actually care about. In production code, this will
            // send a REST request to some 3rd party endpoint.
            .apply("sleep", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws InterruptedException {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    c.output(c.element());
                }
            }));

        return pipeline.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you check [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#rate_limits) that you are indeed not hitting the default quotas ?

Comment: Another idea that comes to my mind is if there is a limiting stage further down the pipeline that would limit the overall throughput, what is the general structure of your pipeline ?

Comment: To your first comment, I don't think we were exceeding the limit on pubsub. We were pulling at 200 messages per second, at the rate of 1.2 Mb/s.

Comment: To your second comment. The pipeline pulls from pubsub -> parse the message into  a data model -> prepare the request query string to 3rd party API -> send the message using Apache httpclient -> prepare Datastore entity if request failed (which never happened) -> save failed data into Datastore (which never happened). It uses reflection to parse input JSON from pubsub into multiple data models (in this case only one), and later on determine how to process the data at runtime. I originally thought there could be a race condition, but behaviour does not support it.

Comment: Here's an easy way to make sure that PubSub is indeed the real issue here, and not problems further down the pipeline. Replace your PubSubIO with a TextIO that reads relevant data in a big text file (and if needed a subsequent stage that formats the data as required). TextIO is extremely performant. If you find your throughput to still be limited like it was with PubSub, you have a bottleneck in your pipeline and that's why your workers can't process PubSub faster.

Comment: I tried to use TextIO as the source, reading a text file from Cloud Storage, and something interesting happened: the throughput did not event get close to a single work when using PubSubIO (4 vs 200 elements/s), even as it scale to 15 workers it only got to 50 elements/s . To be fair, the default machine type for batch only use 1 vCPU for a single worker compare to 4 for streaming.

Comment: If you get 4 elements/s with a TextIO as your  source, I'm pretty sure you have a bottleneck in your pipeline. Unfortunately I don't know an easy tool to automatically detect which stage is causing you this issue. Isn't there a stage that takes significantly more Wall Time than the others ?

Comment: The transform that sends request to the 3rd party API does takes way more wall time than the other ones. I thought about networking limits, but I couldn't find any limit that we are hitting. As for the 4 elements/s, it make sense to me given that with only one thread per worker it can't send multiple requests in parallel. I'm not concerning about the wall time, as it doesn't explain why adding new workers does not increase throughput in the streaming case

Comment: Alright so we have determined that the issue does not come from PubSub, it would be very helpful for others if you could edit your original post so as to reflect what we have found out in our discussion :-) As for further investigating why adding more workers does not help with the stage calling the 3rd party API, I can only make guesses, but could you look up how the CPU usage of each worker evolves over time ? I have had cases where only one worker was active and all the others were near 0% CPU due to bad choices in my pipeline's architecture.

Comment: Update: It turns out could be pubsub in the end. I did another round of comparison between batched job using TextIO and streaming job using PubSubIO, both with "n1-standard-8" machines and fixed number of workers to 15. The batched job went up to 450 elements/s, but the streaming job still peaked at 230 elements/s. Although I'm not sure what was the limitation.

Comment: As for CPU usage, during my previous test, it was around 30% when there was only 1 worker, and once the other 3 workers got online, all of them were at 10% including the first worker.

Comment: Another thing I noticed: during the previous load tests, the number of modify acknowledge deadline operations/requests/byte cost is number of magnitudes higher than pull and acknowledge. Not sure if that has to do with a blockage

Comment: TextIO can read easily around 200k lines per second with only one worker (standard-n4) on my end. If you peak around 450/s with 15 workers, I am **very** inclined to say you have a *huge* bottleneck in your pipeline

Comment: I would like to ask to a minimum piece of your code in order to reproduce your issue and understand or research in deep about the nature of the bottleneck.

Comment: To Temu: I will try to isolate the problem with a minimum code. It might take me to next week to post it.

Comment: To The hBar Tender: Yes I agree with you that there is a huge bottleneck in the pipeline, which is the transform that sends REST request to 3rd party API. That transforms it self take hours of wall time compare to seconds from any other transform. The reason I said I'm not worried about it is that I don't see how this bottleneck can affect parallel execution between 2 workers. Because beam process every element in isolation, a slow transform can only throttle a single worker, and adding new workers should always yield better throughput. To me that is a more concerning problem.

Comment: Update: When I was trying to isolate the issue and create a simple code snippet, I found that the issue is related to both pubsub and the bottleneck transform. The code to reproduce the issue is attached in the **Update 2** section. Without the bottleneck transform, the pipeline was able to pull more than 400 elements/s with a single worker. However with the bottleneck, It can only pull ~ 120 elements/s and adding new workers will not boost performance. I wonder if it has to do with pubsub has to extend acknowledge deadline for most elements, but I can't see how it can cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account that:

1. Switching from PubSubIO to TextIO showed no improvement.
2. Changing from 3 to 15 workers showed no improvement.
3. That batched jobs went up to 450elements/s but streaming peaked at 230elements/s
4. There is a transform that sends REST request to a 3rd party API, taking hours of wall time.
5. In a test, cancelling the transform increases throughput from 120elements/s to 400elements/s.

The issue doesn't seems to lie on PubSub side. According to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#message-flow-control) you might be overloading the 3rd party API. The same effect is explained in documentation for clients, instead of 3rd party APIs:

> It's possible that one client could have a backlog of messages because
>   it doesn't have the capacity to process the volume of incoming
>   messages, but another client on the network does have that capacity.
>   The second client could reduce the overall backlog, but it doesn't get
>   the chance to because the first client cannot send its messages to the
>   second client quickly enough. This reduces the overall rate of
>   processing because messages get stuck on the first client.
>
> The messages that create a backlog consume memory, CPU, and bandwidth
>   resources because the client library continues to extend the messages'
>   acknowledgment deadline.

[...]

> More generally, the need for flow control indicates that messages are
>   being published at a higher rate than they are being consumed. If this
>   is a persistent state, rather than a spike in message volume, consider
>   increasing the number of subscriber client instances and machines.

If you can only work on PubSub to improve the results and you think that the way to achieve this is extending `acknowledgement deadline time` for elements, you can test it by accessing [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/subscriptions/[TOPIC]?project=[PROJECT_ID]) and manually editting the subscription. To do it programmatically using Java, have a look on [this](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#managing_subscriptions) and [this](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/SubscriptionAdminClient.html) documentation, about managing subscriptions and changing `ackDeadlineSeconds` respectively.

Comment: I don't think we are overloading the 3rd party API, as the same behaviour can be reproduced by replacing the API call to `Thread.sleep`. Also I tried extending the PubSub acknowledge deadline to 10 mins, and it had no improvement on the throughput. The extend acknowledge deadline requests started showing up 10 mins later. They were less frequent, but nevertheless present.

Comment: Testing something similar, throughput scales with workers when there are enough Pub/Sub messages to be pulled. At this point, I suggest you to open a [public issue here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) providing the information in the post and your project number, so we can have a look on your specific project.