# Google Dataflow - PubSub to BigQuery - Performance Issue

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I wrote a small Dataflow Script using the Apache Beam Python SDK. It does nothing special, just get data from PubSub and pushing it to BigQuery via the Streaming API.

```
(p
| 'ReadPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=self.threadID)
| 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
| 'ParseJson' >> beam.Map(parse_pubsub)
| 'WritetoBQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            self.name,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
)
```

parse_pubsub is converting the json into dictionary.

The job runs. So far so good. But I found the performance somewhat below my expectations. In PubSub we have up to 92428 events per second, but even with 20 workers (80 vCPU) it only manages to process these events in 15 mins. My only indication that something is off, is the wall time of the last step (beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery) which sums up to "6 days 1 hr" even if the job runs only "15 mins 27 sec" with 20 workers (80 vCPU).

Can you please suggest, if there is anything wrong in the code or is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: You can try going through following link it may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507709/dataflow-autoscale-does-not-boost-performance

Comment: 92428 events per second makes me wonder if you're hitting the Maximum bytes per second quota. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts You could ask for a quota increase or set ignore_insert_ids as True to get 1GB/s. https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.26.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery

Comment: This isn't going to work. BigQuery is not designed for 95k inserts per second. Don't try to write every event in a single shot, you should have a reduce step of some sort that batches up some number of rows.

Comment: Actually, Dataflow connector should retry any failures from  BigQuery due to exceeding rows/sec quota so you should not have to perform flow control manually. I agree with Peter here regarding trying to enable higher streaming insert quota by disabling insert IDs.

Comment: If you are running multiple workers, the "wall time" and "actual time" will always be different. It's the total of the time spent by all workers combined.